# Are Rick and Morty’s Pope-fighting gear callbacks to prior episodes or other shows?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In the episode “Mort: Ragnarick” (season 7, episode 9) of *Rick and Morty*, Rick, Morty, and Bigfoot fight against the Pope in several instances, using various gear. At least one instance is a clear reference to two prior episodes: the *Gundam*-style armor that Rick and Morty first wore in “Promortyus” (season 4, episode 7) and the armor suit from ”Rick & Morty's Thanksploitation Spectacular” (season 5, episode 6).

[image: screencap of instance described above]

But what about the others? Are they also callbacks to previous episodes, or maybe other shows? For example, I noticed that they also used:

- Glass/energy shields 
  [image] [image]
- A futuristic cannon mounted on a wheeled carriage
  [image]
- Pillows as makeshift armor
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The pillow suit idea was also used in [Community S3 E14 - Pillows and Blankets](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2127579/) where Pierce uses a suit of pillows to become a juggernaut in the pillow fort vs. blanket fort pillow fight.

The suits look a bit different.  In Community the head is covered by a pillow with mouth and eye holes, and the duct-tape holding it together is pretty haphazard.

On it's own, I dont think it's enough of a similarity to say it's a reference to that Community episode, but Community and Rick and Morty were both (co-)created by Dan Harmon, and he was still involved in Community during Season 3. So it could easily be a reference to Dan's previous show.

Hopefully someone else can answer for the other gear.

Answer (score 1):

The tower shields made of blue force fields look right out of the Gungan arsenal from *The Phantom Menace*.  The featured prominently in the Gungans' battle with the droid army.

[image: Gungan Shields]

Pillows as a childish version of armor is very old, but one very famous fantasy example occurs in *Through the Looking Glass*, in which Alice helps Tweedledee and Tweedledum prepare for their inevitable battle by tying them round with pillows.  Here is Teniel's illustration from the original edition.

[image: Tweedledum and Tweedledee]